# Equivalent norms example

Tags: real-analysis

Equivalent norms on $\Bbb R^d:$

Show that $||x||_2\leq \sqrt{d}||x||_{\infty}$. When is there inequality?

So, my attempt is this:

So since $x=(x_1,...,x_d)=\sum^d_{j=1}x_je_j$:

$||x||_2=||\sum^d_{j=1}x_je_j||_2\leq\sum^d_{j=1}|x_j|||e_j||\leq||x||_{\infty}\sum^d_{j=1}||e_j||$ and by Cauchy schwarz inequality: $\leq ||x||_{\infty}||\sum^d_{j=1}||e_j||||=||x||_{\infty}\sqrt{d}$

So equality follows if $d=\frac{||x||^2_2}{||x||^2_{\infty}}$

Would this be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a slight error in your line of reasoning, because you had a sum of norms, but then you applied a norm to that sum, which does not make sense (the norm I assume only applies to vectors, but the sum of norms is a scalar). The bound that you would get by correctly analyzing the sum of norms is $d\lVert x \rVert_\infty$, which is loose by a factor of $\sqrt{d}$.

As a hint for the correct approach, note that

$$\lVert x \rVert_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{d}x_i^2}.$$

Apply the step you used (i.e. $|x_i| \leq \lVert x \rVert_\infty$ for any $i$) to the RHS; when does equality hold?

Comment: Assume $x$ is the zero vector. Then $||x||_{\infty}=0=||x||_2$

Assume $x=\sum^d_{j=1}x_je_j$ where $e=(e_1,...,e_d)$ is the canonical basis for $\Bbb R^d$, and where $x_j=0$ for all $j$ except $1$. Then $||x||_{\infty}=1=||x||_2$

Lastly, let $d=\frac{||x||^2_2}{||x||^2_{\infty}}$, then equality follows

Would this be correct?

Answer (score 0):

Let $$ \mathbf{x} \colon= \left( x_1, \ldots, x_d \right) \in \mathbb{R}^d. $$
Then for each $i = 1, \ldots, d$, we have 
$$
0 \leq \left\lvert x_i \right\rvert \leq \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert_\infty,
$$
which implies that
$$
0 \leq \left\lvert x_i \right\rvert^2 \leq \left( \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert_\infty \right)^2.
$$
Hence we have the inequality
$$
0 \leq \sum_{i = 1}^d \left\lvert x_i \right\rvert^2 \leq \sum_{i = 1}^d \left( \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert_\infty \right)^2.
$$
And, since the square root function is a strictly increasing real-valued function defined on $[0, +\infty)$, therefore we find that 
$$
\begin{align}
\lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert_2 &= \sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^d \lvert x_i \rvert^2 } \\
&\leq \sqrt{ \sum_{i = 1}^d \left( \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert_\infty \right)^2 } \\
&= \sqrt{ d \left( \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert_\infty \right)^2 } \\
&= \sqrt{d} \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert.
\end{align}
$$